# Alfresco: Javascript data list creation

Tags: javascript, list, workflow, alfresco

I am attempting to execute some Javascript in my Alfresco workflow to create a custom data list type in my site called "Testing". But before I fill in my custom data list type information, I tried simply creating a contact list data list based on examples I found to make sure it works.

Here is my code:

```js
var site = siteService.getSite("Testing");
var dataLists = site.childByNamePath("dataLists");

if (!dataLists) {
  var dataLists = site.createNode("dataLists", "cm:folder");

  var dataListProps = new Array(1);
  dataListProps["st:componentId"] = "dataLists";
  dataLists.addAspect("st:siteContainer", dataListProps);
  dataLists.save();

  logger.log("Created new datalists folder.");'
}

var contactList = dataLists.childByNamePath("contactlist1");

if (!contactList) {
  var contactList = dataLists.createNode("contactlist1","dl:dataList");

  // tells Share which type of items to create
  contactList.properties["dl:dataListItemType"] = "dl:contact";
  contactList.save();

  var contactListProps = [];
  contactListProps["cm:title"] = "My Contacts";
  contactListProps["cm:description"] = "A contact list generated by a javascript.";
  contactList.addAspect("cm:titled", contactListProps);

  logger.log("Created contact datalist.");

}

var contact = contactList.createNode(null, "dl:contact")
contact.properties["dl:contactFirstName"] = "Florian";
contact.properties["dl:contactLastName"] = "Maul";
contact.properties["dl:contactEmail"] = "info@fme.de";
contact.properties["dl:contactCompany"] = "fme AG";
contact.properties["dl:contactJobTitle"] = "Senior Consultant";
contact.properties["dl:contactPhoneMobile"] = "not available";
contact.properties["dl:contactPhoneOffice"] = "not available";
contact.properties["dl:contactNotes"] = "Alfresco Expert";
contact.save();
logger.log("Created new contact: " + contact.nodeRef);
```

My guess is it's not selecting the right site, but I'm not sure how else to set the site variable to the "Testing" site. Also, I know this code is in the right place in my .bpmn file, because other Javascript in there executes correctly.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? May be you are not having access to siteService.

Comment: @mitpatoliya:I am not sure but , I don't think we can restrict access of siteService or any other service, If its possible , can you tell me how?

Comment: @KrutikJayswal services and alfresco javascript objects avilablity differ based on context in which you are running that, so I did not mean to restrict access anything explicitly.

Comment: I didn't get you,can you tell me any scenario where siteService object is not available in alfresco javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 javascript object on which you have confusion.One is `site` and other is `node`.Site object does not have method called `childByNamePath`.

Instead of that use below for getting datalist.

```
var dataLists = site.getContainer("dataLists");
```

Your code for retrieving site is correct.The only change is for datalist.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Krutik. However, the code is still not working. Would the .childByNamePath() method in the contactList definition be an issue based on your answer?

Comment: Although the contactlist data list works, when I try to implement my own custom list I get this error: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking TaskListener: Exception while invoking TaskListener: 06010016 Failed to execute supplied script: Class {http://www.test.com/model/orpDataListModel/1.0}orpDataListModel has not been defined in the data dictionary